# Can wp-load.php be called in theme functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, wordpress-theming

I can't use wordpress wp_mail() from my themes functions.php.
PHP mail() function works fine but it sends the email using my hosting provider email.
I would like to use my private email, I have installed a plugin to help set the SMTP, the test email sent just fine, but in other to use SMTP in functions.php I need to use wp_mail(), which isn't working.

This is the code in my themes functions.php

```
if($_REQUEST['submitSenda']){
   $nameSenda = $_POST['nameSenda'];
   $emailSenda = $_POST['emailSenda'];
   if(!empty($nameSenda) && !empty($emailSenda)){
       $message = "Hi $nameSenda, is your email $emailSenda?";
       wp_mail($emailSenda, "Invoice", $message);
   }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Please note, I'm not very familiar with wordpress or PHP... I'm just trying to hack my way around it.

Comment: How is it “not working”? Have you verified whether this line gets executed in the first place? Btw., this is rather terrible code. The use of `empty` is just plain wrong, and simply hacking this into the function.php as a “global if” is not really the way things like this should be done inside WP either.

Comment: @misorude How should they be done??

Comment: Which action have you hooked this to?

Comment: @Stender Do you mean html action?